# Error while calling SQL function from java

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

Hi I am trying to call an SQL function from java however I am getting below error:

```
com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: The request for procedure 'getData' failed because 'getData' is a SQL function object.
```

Below java code which is calling the function:

```
String Id = "123";
String result;
Connection conn = null;
CallableStatement scs = null;
try {
    conn = getDatabaseConnection();
    String query = "{? = call getData(?)}";
    scs = conn.prepareCall(query);           
    scs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    scs.setString(2, id);
    scs.executeUpdate();
    result = scs.getString(1);
```

and SQL Function is like:

```
create function getData (@id varchar2) returns char(12)
```

am i missing anything?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the function as below and it worked:

```
String Id = "123";
String result;
Connection conn = null;
CallableStatement scs = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
try {
            conn = getDatabaseConnection();
            String query = "select db.getData(?) ";
            scs = conn.prepareCall(query);
            //Set of parameters
            scs.setString(1, Id);
            //Execution
            resultSet = scs.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                //Get the result
                result = resultSet.getString(1);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jdbc is invoking procedure, but what you defined is function.
See the exception:

The request for **procedure** 'getData' failed because 'getData' **is a SQL function object**

So you have to define getData as procedure not a function.

Comment: but i want it to be a function not procedure and hence in sql I have defined it as function. I want only one value to be returned from function (and hence defined as function).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `scs.execute();` not `scs.executeUpdate();`